# Rails postgres hstore: query for a specific key with any of the given values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql, hstore

My question is specific to rails+postgres hstore datatype.

The `WHERE IN [1,2, 3]` or the rails equivalent `Model.where(data: [1,2,3])` works fine for regular columns, but not for hstore.

I have a hstore column(say `info`) and I want to query for rows which have a particular key and any one of the given values.

For example: To find all books that have a key as 'author' and value as 'ABC' in hstore column, the following query works fine:

`Book.where("info @> hstore(:key, :value)", key: "author", value: "ABC")`

But I need a query that returns records which have a key as 'author' and any one of values in ['ABC', 'XYZ', 'PQRS', 'DFG'].

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
Book.where("(info -> :key) IN (:values)", key: 'author', values: ['ABC', 'XYZ'])
```

However, `@>` has index support, while this won't use any indexes.

Comment: Thanks. That did work but without any index support like you said.